# CURL doesnt show the correct thing

Tags: php

someone told me to use CURL to bypass cloudflare for getting text on a site so i tried it but i just cant understand how i echo out

```
$link1 = "http://habmoon.org/moonstream/djlook?habbie={$r->habbo}";
$link2 = "https://www.habbo.com/habbo-imaging/avatarimage?figure={$link1}";                 
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link1);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

The only thing it shows is $link1 because i dont know how to echo out the text from ***`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link1);`*** in $link2.

Answer (score 0):

Hello friend you need to use CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to get the request output:

```
$ch = curl_init();

$opts = [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'a site',
    CURLTOP_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE
];

curl_setopt_array($opts);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

var_dump($response);
```

And remember, if you need to request a https use a ca file or:

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE
```

Good luck.